# Is it possible to view a tkdiff "report" in tkdiff?

Tags: diff

tkdiff has an option to "Write Report" in the File menu, but I couldn't find any way to open the report in tkdiff later, *i.e.*, so I can view the diff graphically again without having to recompute it.